# Android default photo gallery events

Tags: android

Is there a way to listen to photo gallery events via some background service to open a selected photo in my activity. Share a photo is the only mechanism it seems.

Comment: What are "photo gallery events" and what do they have to do with "open a selected photo in [your] activity"?

Comment: I want to open the current selected photo in photo gallery in my application. To my knowledge I am aware of sharing the image. But is there a direct way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of "photo gallery" applications. None should be letting third party apps know what image(s) the user is looking at, except at user request, such as via some sort of "share" option. Any app that *did* disclose this information has a privacy flaw that would need to be fixed.

If you feel that the share option is insufficient, you can write your own photo gallery app and take actions as the user browses photos within your own gallery.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this doubt I was dealing with for so long :). Thank you very much